# Adding the case number and link to an email

Tags: email, email-template, case

If I am sending an email from within a case, how can I get the email to contain the case number and the link to the case automatically/by default?

Answer (score 2):

Use an email template, and set the following mergefields in your template:

- {!Case.CaseNumber} for the number
- {!Case.Link} for the url to the specific case

If you want to create a button that pre-selects your email-template, so you only have to click send

create a custom button, and fill in the following parameters in the URL

- Base URL: /_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?
- p2_lkid: {object ID} *Who we are sending it to, a contact id for
  example*
- rtype: {type of the object we are sending to} *This is the type of
  the sobject we're sending to, for example 003 for Contact*
- p3_lkid: {object ID} *What we are relating this to, this is your case id*
- template_id: {object ID} *Id of your template*
- save=1
- saveURL=%2F{object ID}  *where do we go after send, this is most likely your case id*

For example:

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid=003S000000XXXXX&rtype=003&p3_lkid=500S000000XXXXX&p26=test@test.com&template_id=00X700000015WDiEAM&retURL=%2F500S000000XXXXX
```

Comment: bbbut, would I have to select the template every time a create an email from the case? I wouldn't want that...

Comment: You can also create a button that pre-selects an email-template, i'll add that to my answer, sec!